# How to (add/import/reference) needed Modules for making executables from scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4, py2exe

Win 10, Python 3.4, PyQT 4.11, py2exe 0.9.2.2

I am trying to make executables from my scripts but receive following:

```
  D:\Repos\GateManagement>py -3.4 -m py2exe.build_exe main.pyw

  5 missing Modules
  ------------------
  ? Queue imported from mysql.connector.pooling
  ? System imported from serial.serialcli
  ? _mysql_connector imported from mysql.connector, mysql.connector.connection_cext, mysql.connector.cursor_cext
  ? readline imported from cmd, code, pdb
  ? xmlrpclib imported from mysql.connector.fabric.connection
  Building 'dist\main.exe'.
```

How to add (reference to, or whatever) these 5 missing modules?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It turns out I can't use .pyw but .py